# Remove Jquery Mobile Checkbox Overlay

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, checkbox, themes

I want to display the default checkboxes and remove the overlay that Jquery Mobile adds over the checkbox.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2-1a" id="checkbox2-1a"  />
     <label for="checkbox2-1a">Lorem ipsum</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2-2a" id="checkbox2-2a"  />
     <label for="checkbox2-2a">Dolor</label>
</fieldset>
```

I want to keep the JQM checkbox styles for some checkboxes, but on these selected ones, remove it completely so that the browser default displays.

I tried data-theme="none," but these styles appear to be in the jquery.mobile.structure.css, which is minified.

I am hoping to avoid creating overrides and a custom class for each input. Is there a better way or a way that already exists inside JQM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data-role="none" to the inputs:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
     <input data-role="none" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2-1a" id="checkbox2-1a"  />
     <label for="checkbox2-1a">Lorem ipsum</label>
     <input data-role="none"  type="checkbox" name="checkbox2-2a" id="checkbox2-2a"  />
     <label for="checkbox2-2a">Dolor</label>
</fieldset>
```